# How to shrink hard disk more effectively

Tags: windows-7

How to shrink a partition with unmovable files in Windows 7

http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/how-to-shrink-a-partition-with-unmovable-files-in-windows-7

> Says that the way to do it: 1- Disable System Restore (Right click on
>   Computer => Properties => System Protection => System Restore) 2-
>   Disable Virtual Memory (Right click on Comptuer => Properties =>
>   Advanced System Settings => Performance (Settings) => Advanced Tab =>
>   Virtual Memory (Change) => No Paging File => Set. 3- Run Disk Cleanup
>   to get rid of Thumbnails, Temporary Internet Files, and a bunch of
>   other files that it makes no sense why they are immovable. 4- Restart
>   the computer to have #1 and #2 take effect
>
> Try to shrink the volume again. If it still is unreasonably large, you
>   will then have to look at Event Viewer to find which file is at the
>   boundary. 1- Right click on Computer => Manage => Event Viewer =>
>   Windows Logs => Application. 2- Click on Filter Current Log, and put
>   ’259′ for the Event ID 3- Click on the latest event and look through
>   the detail to find the problematic file. You can then attempt to
>   delete that file (or set of files) manually. You may have to restart
>   into safe mode to delete some files
>
> It took me about 5 loops of doing the above before I was finally able
>   to shrink my volume to the size that I wanted. After successful, you
>   can then re-enable the features that you want (namely System Restore
>   and Virtual Memory)

```
The problem is the file that's problematic for me is:
\System Volume Information\{4ebf1c32-6152-11e2-95c2-1078d23b5db1}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}::$DATA
 - The last cluster of the file is: 0x1dc204a
 - Shrink potential target (LCN address): 0x1604d70
 - The NTFS file flags are: ---AD
 - Shrink phase: <analysis>
```

I think it's too complicated. Not to mention that system volume information is a prety important file.

My plan is to do defragment before boot.

Will that help?

Can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

Defraggler has an option to move all data to the beginning of a partition. But you have to boot it from a live media (eg. Hiren's Boot CD, works also from USB).

Comment: defraggler do not have an option to create bootable CD

Comment: there is a boot time defrag but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: You need a 3rd-party CD with Defraggler on it, like the *Hiren's Boot CD* I mentioned. Boot Mini XP from HBCD, then in launcher choose *Optimizers -> Defraggler* and from menu select *Action -> Advanced -> Defrag freespace*.